# Custom "Add Data" - how to post data to PHP server?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jqgrid

I have the following PHP script:

```
$OperMode = $_POST['oper']; 
switch($OperMode) {
/* [...] */
case 'ManAdd':
            // get data
            $Firma = $_POST['Name'];
            $Adresse = $_POST['Address'];
            $PLZ = $_POST['PLZ'];
            $Ort = $_POST['Ort'];
            $TelNr = $_POST['TelNr'];
            /* [...] */
            // save data to SQL database with adapted strings
            $Insert ="INSERT INTO adresse (Nachname, Vorname, Strasse, Hausnummer, Postleitzahl, Ort, Telefonnummer) VALUES('$Nachname', '$Vorname', '$Strasse', '$Hausnummer', '$PLZ', '$Ort', '$TelNr')";
            if(mysql_query($Insert)) {
                echo "Eintrag erfolgreich."; // Successful
            } else {
                die("Eintrag nicht erfolgreich!<br>Telefonnummer existiert bereits!"); // Not successful
            }               
            break;
```

Now I'd like to save selected rows from a jqGrid with the PHP script above.
Here is the code of the grid and a custom button:

```
$("#ResultGrid")
                .jqGrid({
                    colNames:['Firma', 'Adresse', 'Postleitzahl', 'Ort', 'Telefonnummer'],
                    colModel:[
                    {name:'Firma', index:'Firma', width:175, searchable:false},
                    {name:'Adresse', index:'Adresse', width:160, searchable:false},
                    {name:'Postleitzahl', index:'Postleitzahl', width:100, searchable:false, sorttype:'int'},
                    {name:'Ort', index:'Ort', width:150, searchable:false},
                    {name:'Telefonnummer', index:'Telefonnummer', width:160, searchable:false}
                    ],
                    datatype: "clientSide",
                    editurl:'Edit.php',
                    height: 'auto',
                    loadonce: true,
                    multiselect: true,
                    pager:'#ResultPager',
                    rownum:-1,
                })
                .navGrid('#ResultPager', {view:false, edit:false, add:false, del:false, search:false, refresh:false} )
                .navButtonAdd('#ResultPager', {title:"Adresse ins Addressbuch übernehmen", buttonicon:"ui-icon-disk", caption:"Speichern", onClickButton:function(){
                    if($("#ResultGrid").getGridParam('selrow') == null || $("#ResultGrid").getGridParam('selrow') == undefined) {
                        $("#Dialog").html("<p><span class=\"ui-icon ui-icon-info\" style=\"float:left; margin:0 7px 20px 0;\"></span>Bitte eine Adresse ausw&auml;hlen!</p>");
                        $("#Dialog").dialog("option", "title", "Hinweis:");
                        $("#Dialog").dialog("open");
                    } else {
                        var ID = $("#ResultGrid").getGridParam('selrow');
                        var AddressRow = $("#ResultGrid").getRowData(ID);                       
                        // The data to be stored:
                        var NameLine = AddressRow.Firma;
                        var AddressLine = AddressRow.Adresse;
                        var ZipCode = AddressRow.Postleitzahl;
                        var City = AddressRow.Ort;
                        var PhoneNumber = AddressRow.Telefonnummer;

                      $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'Edit.php',
                    dataType: // ???
                    data: // ???                    
                        });                   
                    }
                }})
```

I need to post the operation mode "ManAdd" (oper = "ManAdd") and the address to the server.
In this case which datatype is needed and how is the data option constructed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that it would be enough to set no `dataType` and to use as the `data` parameter  something like following:

```
data: {oper: 'ManAdd', Name: NameLine, Address: AddressLine, PLZ: ZipCode,
       Ort: City, TelNr: PhoneNumber}
```